# OpenGL: Render into FBO with depth attachment, while reading from same depth texture, with glDepthMask being false

Tags: opengl, textures, fbo

I know that it is an error to render into an FBO while simultaneously fetching from the depth texture attached to this FBO (at least without the texture_barrier extension).

However, is it also an error to do so if glDepthMask is false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feedback loops are not errors; they're undefined behavior. If they were errors, you could just try it and see if it fails.

If you are not on GL 4.5 or ARB_texture_barrier (or NV_texture_barrier) is not available, then doing as you suggest will yield undefined behavior.

The [rules for feedback loops before that feature](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Memory_Model#Framebuffer_objects) were quite draconian. Those rules only cares about what is attached and bound. The simple act of attaching the texture to the FBO and binding it for access by the shader invokes undefined behavior. The only state that could prevent it is the use of mipmap base/max levels to make it impossible for the shader to access the mipmap level attached to the FBO.

If you did have access to GL 4.5/ARB_texture_barrier/NV_texture_barrier, then it should work... provided that you use a barrier before you switch over to reading. The new text makes it clear that it is reading data that has been written (by fragment shader outputs) that is the problem, and the depth mask prevents writing from happening. And with the texture barrier in place, you make the previously written data available to shaders.

Comment: small follow up. The site you linked states "undefined behavior is still triggered whenever a shader attempts to read from texels written by a prior rendering call (unless the image is actually detached from the FBO before the read)" - instead of detaching, is binding a different draw fbo, drawing something, and then binding the original FBO again and then performing the simultaneous read/draw without a call to glTextureBarrier defined behaviour (if the extension is available)?

Comment: @user1282931: A feedback loop requires that the texture is simultaneously bound for reading and attached to the *current* FBO. If that's not the case, then there's no problem.

Comment: I mean the following: 1.) texture_barrier extension is available. 2.) Geometry is rendered into FBO A. 3.) depth texture of FBO A is bound for reading and fullscreen quad is rendered to FBO B. 4.) depth texture of FBO A is bound for reading and a fullscreen quad is rendered into FBO A. - question is whether in this case a glTextureBarrier() call is necessary before step 4?